# How to set up special offer bundles of products?

Tags: products

i want to set up some bundle offers for products...
i have read extensively about the different product types of magento but still cant see what i am after...

I am wanting to take 5 or 6 or my existing simple products, bundle them together and create a page all about the offer, and then put an offer price on them if they are bought together...

Any idea how to go about this?

Thanks all

Comment: Weigh up the difference between group products and bundles, then choose whichever suits you best. Then you can create the product in admin and assign your 5-6 simples to it, set your prices etc.

Comment: Robbiethanks - everytime i have done this ir doesnt display a fixed price for the bundle - plus i dont want and options for change...

Comment: Try a group product instead. Fixed price should be implied with one of them but I can't remember which